# Some `fontawsome` icons cause build errors when enabling Japanese support

Tags: moderncv, cjk, fontawesome, japanese, fontawesome5

When using `moderncv`, enabling some kind of Japanese support (e.g. with `luatexja` or `babel`) makes it impossible to use some certain `fontawesome` icons, giving build errors such as `Missing font identifier.`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{luatexja}

% this also causes an error even without luatexja
% \usepackage[english]{babel}
% \babelprovide[import]{japanese}

\begin{document}
\faGlobeAmericas{} % this is fine
\faLinkedin{} % this causes the build error
\end{document}
```

What are some possible solutions? (I need support for both partial and full Japanese document)

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer but to long for a comment.

I can't reproduce your claim that it fails with babel, but with luatexja the problem is a conflict with microtype. It fails for the one icon as a font substituation is involved in this case.

E.g. if you use an unknown series

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{luatexja}

\begin{document}

\fontseries{blub}\selectfont abc

\end{document}
```

you typically get a warning like this

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmr/blub/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 170.
```

If you enable microtype and luatexja you get the missing font identifier error:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmr/blub/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 170.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT3/mc/blub/n' undefined
(Font)              using `JT3/mc/m/n' instead on input line 170.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 170.
! Missing font identifier.
<to be read again> 
JT3/mc/m/n/10 
l.170 \fontseries{blub}\selectfont
                                 abc
```

luatex-ja patches microtype, and I get actually even a warning that this perhaps doesn't work, so I would suggest to report the problem in the luatex-ja tracker.

```
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-microtype.sty

Package luatexja Warning: LuaTeX-ja's patch against the microtype package 
(luatexja)                (lltjp-microtype.sty, 2019-11-08) may not work.
```